# Question about proof that a closed Lie subgroup is embedded in John Lee's Smooth Manifolds: constructing a slice chart

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Below is part of the proof that for a Lie group $G$ and a Lie subgroup $H\subset G$, if $H$ is closed in $G$ then it is embedded (Theorem 7.21 of John Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds).

The proof assumes that the dimension of $H$ is less than the dimension of $G$. The goal is to show that for some $h_1 \in H$, there is a neighborhood $U_1$ of $h_1$ in $G$ such that $H \cap U_1$ is an embedded submanifold of $U_1$.

We first construct a slice chart $(U,\phi)$ for $V$ in $G$ where $V$ is a neighborhood of $e$ in $H$. Then we can assume that $U \cap V$ is the slice $(x^1, \dots, x^m,0,\dots, 0)$. Also we can define $S \subset U$ to be the set of points with coordinates $(0,\dots, 0, x^{m+1}, \dots, x^n)$, which is the slice perpendicular to $U\cap V$.

Then we define the map $\psi:V\times S \to G$ as the group multiplication map and find a neighborhood $V_0 \times S_0$, where $V_0$ and $S_0$ are neighborhoods of $e$ in $V$ and $S$ respectively, and $U_0$ a neighborhood of $e$ in $G$ such that $\psi: W_0 \to U_0$ is a diffeomorphism.

Given these, in the final line of the proof, it states that $U_1 = \psi(V_0 \times S_1)$ is a neighborhood of $h_1$ in $G$ with the property that $U_1 \cap H$ is the slice $\psi(V_0 \times \{h_1\})$ in $U_1$.

**My question is why is $\psi(V_0 \times \{h_1\})$ a slice in $U_1$?** I can't figure out how to show that this gives a slice chart. I would greatly appreciate some help about this proof.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We need to show that
$$\psi\left(V_0 \times\left\{h_1\right\}\right)=U_1 \cap H.$$
Let $h\in \psi\left(V_0 \times\left\{h_1\right\}\right)$ then exists $v\in V_0$ such that $h=v\cdot h_1$. So, $h\in H\cap U_1$.

Now let $h^\prime $ be an element of $U_1 \cap H.$ Thus exists $s \in S_1$ and $v\in V_0$ such that $v\cdot s=h^\prime$. This implies that $s=v^{-1}\cdot h^{\prime}$ is an element of $H$. However $S_1\cap H=\{h_1\}$, hence $h^\prime \in \psi\left(V_0 \times\left\{h_1\right\}\right)$.

Edit:
This is indeed a slice chart. $\psi_{\restriction V_0 \times S_1}$ is a diffeomorphism as $V_0 \times S_1\subset W_0$. We can now map $V_0 \times S_1\to R^{2n}$ by $(x,y)\mapsto (\phi(x),\phi(y)).$ By definition of $S$ and $V$ this map will be given in coordinates by
$$(x^1\ldots,x^m,0,\ldots,0,x^{m+1},\ldots,x^n).$$
Then, forgetting the $0,\ldots,0$ in the middle, we get the desired slice chart and $$\psi\left(V_0 \times\left\{h_1\right\}\right)\cong\{(x^1,\ldots,x^m,\phi(h_1) )|(x_1,\ldots,x^m) \text{ are the coordinate given for } V_0 \}$$

Comment: I know that $\psi(V_0 \times \{h_1\}) = U_1 \cap H$. My question is why is $\psi(V_0 \times \{h_1\})$ a slice chart in $U_1$.

Comment: I edited the answer. Is it all clear now?

Comment: Why is the map $v \mapsto v\cdot h_1$ an immersion?

Comment: its a composition of the immersion $V_0 \to V_0 \times S_1$ given by $v \mapsto (v,h_1)$ and a diffeomorphism $V_0 \times S_1 \to \psi(V_0 \times S_1) $

Comment: $v\mapsto (v,h_1)$ is an immersion because the differential is equal to the differential of the first component and the second component, where the first is the identity and the second is $0$ so is injective?

Comment: The charts of the Cartesian product of manifolds are the Cartesian product of the charts (See Example 1.8 in the book). This is how you show what you have just written in the comments.

Comment: I’m not sure about the rank theorem used here. The rank theorem is local so the coordinate representation is obtained for some chart contained in $V_0$ hence how can we conclude thag $\psi(V_0 \times h_1)$  is the slice $(x^1,\dots,x^m,0,\dots,0)$?

Comment: You are correct i gave a diffrent chart now

Comment: I assume $\phi$ is $\varphi$ in the text. Why is the map $(x,y)\mapsto (\phi(x),\phi(y))$ given in coordinates by $(x^1,\dots , x^m,0,\dots,0,x^{m+1},\dots,x^n)$? And why is $\psi\left(V_0 \times\left\{h_1\right\}\right)\cong\{(x^1,\ldots,x^m,\phi(h_1) )|(x_1,\ldots,x^m) \text{ are the coordinate given for } V_0 \}$?

Comment: Also why would $\{(x^1,\ldots,x^m,\phi(h_1) )|(x_1,\ldots,x^m) \text{ are the coordinate given for } V_0 \}$ be a slice chart? And where is $\psi|_{V_0 \times S_1}$ used here?

Comment: I can see where you get $(x^1,\dots, x^m,0,\dots,0,x^{m+1},\dots,x^n)$ for $(\phi(x),\phi(y))$, but $\phi$ has the domain $U$, so I think we would need $U\cap V_0$.

Comment: Could you explain my questions and concerns?

Answer (score 1):

Let me give this a try.

So we have that the group multiplication $\psi: V_0\times S_0\to U_0$ is a diffeomorphism. Here $V_0\subset V$ has coordinates $(x^1, \dots, x^m)$ and $S_0\subset S$ has coordinates $(x^{m+1}, \dots, x^n)$, induced from their slice structure in the original $U$.

**Here is the main point, to me.** Since $\psi$ is a diffeomorphism, we use **new** coordinates on $U_0$ coming from this diffeomorphism. That is, the coordinates of $g\in U_0$ are the above coordinates of $\pi_{V_0}(\psi^{-1}(g))$ and $\pi_{S_0}(\psi^{-1}(g))$ put together.

This is a **different** coordinate system from the original one on $U$, since here we use the group multiplication. It is with this new coordinate sysmten that you can see the slice structure.

Now we find $h_1\in S_0\cap H$ with a neighborhood $S_1\subset S_0$ such that $S_1\cap H = \{h\}$. Then consider the restricted diffeomorphism $\psi: V_0\times S_1\to U_1$, where $U_1=\psi(V_0\times S_1)\subset U_0$ with the above new coordinates.

Now $U_1\cap H = \psi(V_0\times \{h_1\})$, and in the new coordinates on $U_1$, the points in $\psi(V_0\times \{h_1\})$ have coordinates
$$
(x^1,\dots, x^m, c^{m+1},\dots, c^n)
$$
where $(c^{m+1},\dots,c^n)$ are the coordinates of $h_1\in S_1\subset S_0$.

Hence $\psi(V_0\times \{h_1\})$ is a slice in $U_1$, just at some other constant values. See p. 101 of Lee's book for this natural generalization.

Comment: Are you assuming $V_0 \subset V \cap U$?

Comment: Yes, we do assume that. You are right, and it is without loss of generality to take $U\cap V$ to be the new $V$. Then this totally matches Lee's writing, since he only seems to be explicitly writing $V_0\subset V$.