# question about the proof of the local slice condition for embedded submanifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

This is the proof of Theorem 5.8 the local slice criterion for embedded submanifolds from John Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds. In this proof, why does the author consider coordinate balls $U_0\subset U$ and $V_0 \subset V$? From the inclusion map and its coordinate representation, isn't it already true that $U=\iota(U)$ is exactly a single slice in $V$? What goes wrong if we don't restrict it to coordinate balls?

[image]

Comment: For starters, are charts required to be connected?

Comment: @TedShifrin No just an open subset diffeomorphic to an open subset in $R^n$

Comment: Right. So that's one reason Lee wants to shrink to a ball (or a connected open set).

Comment: @TedShifrin Why is connected necessary here? The rank theorem guarantee already that $(x^1,\dots, x^k)\mapsto (x^1,\dots,x^k,0,\dots,0)$ for $\iota|_U:U \to V$ and so $\iota(U)$ is already of the form $(x^1,\dots,x^k,0,\dots,0)$ which is a slice?

Comment: But why is nothing else from $S$ appearing in the open set?

Comment: @TedShifrin I don't understand what you mean by nothing else from $S$ appearing in the open set.

Comment: Take $S$ that leaves $V$ and comes back into it.

Comment: @TedShifrin Sorry I really don't understand your language here. What do you mean that it leaves $V$ and comes back into it?

Comment: @TedShifrin I can’t see where the argument goes wrong if we replace all $U_0$ and $V_0$ by $U$ and $V$.

Comment: You do not know that $\iota(U)=V\cap S$.

Comment: @TedShifrin that’s true but if we follow the argument with $U$ and $V$ instead of $U_0$ and $V_0$ we have $V_1\cap S=U$ which is a single slice of $V$ by the coordinate representation we have.

Comment: No, that coordinate representation is local at $p$. Again, that is not necessarily representing all points of $S$ in $V$.

Comment: @TedShifrin What is wrong with being local? So you mean $V\cap S \neq U$?

Comment: And why does using a connected open set resolve any issue?

Comment: Connectedness is of course not enough. But you can easily create counterexamples by taking $V$ to be a union of open sets, each containing a slice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point @TedShifrin is making is that the rank theorem only guarantees the relation $U\subset V$, hence it may not be the case that $V\cap S=U$. In particular, you require that every point in $V\cap S$ has coordinate representation

$$
(x^1,\ldots,x^k,0,\ldots,0),
$$

but only the points in $U\subset V\cap S$ have this coordinate representation (the points in $(V\cap S)\setminus U$ could look different).

Edit: Also, Lee defines $S$ to satisfy the local $k$-slice condition if every point in $S$ has a chart $V$ in $M$ such that $V\cap S$ is a single $k$-slice.

Essentially, by restricting to coordinate balls $U_0$ and $V_0$ contained inside of $U$ and $V$, respectively, we guarantee that $U_0$ is a single $k$-slice in $V_0$. By defining the set $V_1$, we guarantee that $V_1\cap S=U_0$.

Comment: Thank you but why does the equality hold if we replace $U$ and $V$ by connected open sets as Ted commented?

Comment: @nomadicmathematician Sorry, I should edit my answer. The point is that Lee defines $S$ to satisfy the local $k$-slice condition if every point in $S$ has a chart $V$ in $M$ such that $V\cap S$ is a single $k$-slice. In particular, it may be the case a priori that $U$ is multiple $k$-slices in $V$ (imagine $U$ looking like two disjoint hyperplanes). So by replacing $U$ and $V$ with $U_0$ and $V_0$ you may ensure $U_0$ is a single $k$-slice in $V_0$. Finally, by replacing $V_0$ with $V_1$, you may ensure $V_1\cap S=U_0$.

Comment: What do you mean $U$ can be multiple k slices in $V$? Doesn’t the coordinate representation ensure injectivity?

Comment: @nomadicmathematician Yes, it is injective. What I mean is that $V$ could look like the 3-dimensional unit ball, $U$ could look five disjoint 2-planes inside of the ball, and $(V\cap S)\setminus U$ could look like some crazy surface. So you have to make $U$ look like one 2-plane, and you have to make $V\cap S$ look like $U$.

Comment: If $V$ is the 3-dim unit ball then doesn't the constraint requires $U$ to have zero $z$-axis? So how do we get disjoint 2-planes inside of the ball? And I get that $V\cap S\neq U$. But I can't see why $V_1 \cap S \neq U$? Following the argument without $U_0$ and $V_0$ we still have $U=\iota(U)$ is a single slice in $V$. And $U$ open in $S$ means $U=W\cap S$ for some open subset $W\subset M$. Setting $V_1=V\cap W$ we have $V_1 \cap S=V\cap W\cap S = V \cap U = U$. This is true simply from set relations. What's wrong with this?

Comment: @nomadicmathematician My wording was misleading. Consider the case that $U$ is a bunch of disjoint subspaces of the $(x,y)$-plane (so $U$ "looks like" disjoint 2-planes, at least locally) and $V$ contains all of this. Then $V$ contains "multiple" $k$-slices. You want to contain a "single" $k$-slice.

Comment: Ok I get the idea. But isn't $V_1 \cap S=U$ true if we set $V_1 = V \cap W$ where $U=W \cap S$?

Comment: @nomadicmathematician Yes that's true, but then $V_1$ would "look like" 3-balls each centered around some slice, where one of those slices contains your original point $p$. You just want to restrict to that 3-ball and that exact slice. Hope this helps!

Comment: Could you take a look at this question? The answer uses the rank theorem as well, but I don't think the rank theorem alone gives a slice chart. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4828331/question-about-proof-that-a-closed-lie-subgroup-is-embedded-in-john-lees-smooth/4829196?noredirect=1#comment10280934_4829196